# java how to replace N number of spaces using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I like to display a text (input text in textArea) nicely in web page. So need to

```
    1. change linebreaker \n to <br/>
    2. keep indentation: 
             replace 2 spaces with one space and &nbsp; 
             replace 3 spaces with one space and 2 &nbsp; 
             replace 4 spaces with one space and 3 &nbsp; 
             replace N spaces with one space and N-1 &nbsp;
```

Is there a way to replace the spaces using regular expression in JAVA?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes there certainly is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: That indentation is going to look pretty bad with a proportional font. If the text is code as implied by the need for indentation, why not use `<pre>` tags?

Comment: User do not add <pre> around code in textArea. Server side do not know which part is code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores represent spaces:
Find: `(?<=_)_`
Replace: `&nbsp;`

If you have to stick with regex, [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is what you're looking for.
Basically, this will match each space which follows another space.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
String oldString="";
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\n", "<br />").replaceAll("(?<= ) ", "&nbsp;");
```